# Using try/except in Python 3

Tags: exception, python-3.x

I want to prompt the user with a separate exception error if they have entered a float over any other invalid string. Currently I get the same error if a string like "hello" is entered or a float like 2.5. Which exception should I be using just to filter float values? Thanks

```
print('Enter 1 for option 1')
print('Enter 2 for option 2')
print('Enter 3 for option 3')
print('Enter 4 to quit')

flag = True
x = -1
while(flag):

        try:
            x  = (int(input('Enter your choice: ')))
            if((x >= 1) and (x <= 4)):
                flag = False
                x = x
            else:
                print('The number should be between 1 and 4')
        except TypeError:
            print('Choice should be an integer not a float')
        except ValueError:
            print('Choice should be a number')
        except NameError:
            print('Choice should be a number')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you're having is due to `int` raising the same exception for all invalid strings, whether they represent floats or just random text. Here's one way you could solve that:

```
while True:
    try:
        s = input("Enter a number 1-4")
        x = int(x)      # this will raise a ValueError if s can't be made into an int
        if 1 <= x <= 4:
            break
        print("The number must be between 1 and 4")
    except ValueError:
        try:
            float(s)    # will raise another ValueError if s can't be made into a float
            print("You must enter an integer, rather than a floating point number.")
        except ValueError:
            print("You must enter a number.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... how about this?

```
x = input('Enter your choice: ')
if float(x) != int(x):
    raise TypeError
x = int(x)
```